# I don't want to play with it right now. The screen is on all day

Tags: screen-saver

Just installed Raspberry Pi 400 keyboard with a monitor for my daughter.

She has a game of xsolitaire up and went to school.

That game is still on the screen 5 hours later.

How to turn on sleep or screensaver mode?

Comment: pull the plug ..

Comment: the title of your post does not match the question ... please correct it

Comment: Which OS are you using? That may make a difference b/c they changed to ***wayland*** in the latest (bookworm?) release.  There's [this old answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/4608/make-display-go-to-sleep) which may or m ay not help. Let us know.

Comment: Might try add `hdmi_blanking=1` in /boot/config.txt.

Answer (score 1):

**Raspberry Pi Configuration** menu has a **Display** setting which allows **Screen Blanking** after a period of inactivity (10 minutes default).